# Terraform - Loop over datasource and create map, pass this map to module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to loop over `secrets` datasource with `grafana-secrets` list.
This output should be mapped as `env_secrets` inside module.
Now module will use this map as `vars = {}` (even if its empty, its generic module) and will template file.

Here is my *NONWORKING* use case just for ilustration:

```
variable "grafana-secrets" {
  type = "list"

  default = ["GF_DATABASE_USER","GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET","GF_SESSION_PROVIDER_CONFIG"]
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secrets" {
  count     = "${length(var.grafana-secrets)}"
  name      = "${element(var.grafana-secrets, count.index)}"
  vault_uri = "https://foobar.vault.azure.net/"
}

module "grafana" {
   source = "modules/deployment"

   env_secrets = {
     "${element(var.grafana-secrets, count.index)}" = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.secret.*.value
   }
}
```

modules/deployment:

```
data "template_file" "template" {
  template = ".secrets"

  vars = "${merge(
    env_secrets,
    map(
      "dummy", "dummy"
    )
  )}"
}
```

Comment: It looks like your only problem is creating the map for the `env_secrets` variable for the `grafana` module. If that is the case, you can use `zipmap` to accomplish this as explained at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55003757/build-output-map-in-terraform/55006832#55006832

Comment: Thanks. But I am not sure if I can pass map to module. 
This: `env_secrets = "${zipmap(element(var.grafana-secrets, count.index),element(data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.secrets.*.value, count.index))}"` is not working for me

Comment: If you check the linked answer or the doc linked in the answer, it states that the arguments are lists and not strings. You need to provide lists as the arguments and not their string elements.

Comment: You are right, `vars = "${zipmap(var.grafana-secrets,data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.secrets.*.value)}"` works for datasource, but not for module